# When I (byte-compile-file "my-package.el"), can I treat warnings as errors?

Tags: byte-compilation, error-handling, warning

As part of CI testing, I'm byte-compiling package files to make sure there are no errors.  I'd like to take this a step further and ensure there are no *warnings*, either (like 'function not known to be defined', etc.).

Is there a variable I can let-bind to make this happen?  `apropos` was not very enlightening.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "treat warnings as errors"? Are you asking for a way of having each byte-compiler warning raise an error?

Comment: @Drew exactly. I want my test to fail if there are any byte-compile warnings. (By the way, I *do* thing [tag:package-development] is appropriate here; this is part of the dev process.)

Comment: Sounds like the equivalent of `-Werror` in contemporary C compilers to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for the customisable variable `byte-compile-error-on-warn` says:

```
If true, the byte-compiler reports warnings with `error'.
```